# ObjectCreatedByPut in S3 on Bucket level invokes Lambda multiple times for single upload

Tags: lambda

We have created the Lambda function with ObjectCreatedByPut event from S3 bucket (no Filter). The lambda's objective is  to create/update/start the codepipeline based on a Git Branch. The codepipeline has a SNS approval stage. Now we noticed that until the SNS Approval stage is rejected for the Codepipeline flow, the Lambda is re-invoked multiple times after every Codepipeline passes the SNS approval stage even though the S3 object remains unchanged. It seems the Lambda gets self-invoked multiple invocations. 
Is there any specific reason why its getting invoked like this even when we are not changing the object?
It has been seen if we use a filter in S3 bucket for Lambda to invoke from a specific folder of the bucket, this scenario doesn't occur. Please explain the behaviour. 
I recreated the Lambda Function, however it still multiple times invocations for the same event which is undesired. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the aws lambda invocation documentation helps below:

> For **asynchronous** invocation, Lambda adds events to a queue before
> sending them to your function. **If** your function does not have
> enough capacity to keep up with the queue, events may be lost.
> **Occasionally,**
> **your function may receive the same event multiple times, even if no**
> **error occurs.** To retain events that were not processed, configure your function with a dead-letter queue.

Is your function asynchronous or synchronous?  If events are getting queued they may be executing twice , or a least more than once.

I would suggest you test both behaviors and share the results if you are seeing a a behavior that is not predictable.

Ref:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-sync.html
```